# Diffing two objects and getting only updates

Tags: javascript, diff, lodash

I'm trying to diff two objects and only get updates.

```
let alpha = {
 brown: true,
 green: true,
 blue: true
}

let beta = {
 green: false,
}

doSomething(alpha, beta) // => {green: false}

let alpha = {
 brown: true,
 green: true,
 blue: true
}

let beta = {
 green: true,
}

doSomething(alpha, beta) // => false
```

So far this is what I've got.

```
let alphaSameKeys = pick(alpha, Object.keys(beta))
console.log(alpha) // => {green: true}
```

How do I finish this off using lodash?

Comment: I would look into https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch

Answer (score 0):

Simple shallow diff.

```
export function diffObject (source, incoming) {
  let res = pickBy(incoming, (value, key) => {
    if (value !== source[key]) return true
    if (!source[key]) return true
    return false
  })
  if (!size(res)) return false
  return res
}
```